# Detect the status of a printer paper

Tags: delphi, printing

i need to get paper status information from a printer. I have a list of esc/pos commands. 
I'm trying to send these comands with escape function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This is my code

```
type
TPrnBuffRec = record
  bufflength: Word;
  Buff_1: array[0..255] of Char;
end;

procedure TFTestStampa.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buff: TPrnBuffRec;
  BuffOut: TPrnBuffRec;
  TestInt: Integer;
  cmd : string;
begin
  printer.BeginDoc;

  try
    TestInt := PassThrough;
    if Escape(Printer.Handle, QUERYESCSUPPORT, SizeOf(TESTINT),
@testint, nil) > 0 then
      begin
        cmd := chr(10) + chr(04) + '4';
        StrPCopy(Buff.Buff_1, cmd);
        Buff.bufflength := StrLen(Buff.Buff_1);
        Escape(Printer.Canvas.Handle, Passthrough, 0, @buff,
@buffOut);

        ShowMessage( conver(strPas(buffOut.Buff_1)) );
      end

  finally
    printer.EndDoc;

end;


function TFTestStampa.Conver(s: string): String;
var
  i:  Byte;
  t : String;
begin
  t := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(s)  do
    t := t + IntToHex(Ord(s[i]), 2) + ' ';
  Result := t;
end;
```

Problem is with different cmds I obtain always the same string ....
Can you give me an example of escape function with last parameter not nill ?
Alternatives to obtain paper status ?

Comment: Am I reading correctly buffout ?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using Delphi 2009 above and you used [`this source`](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=716) for your example, so your problem might be caused by Unicode parameters. In Delphi since version 2009, `string` type is defined as `UnicodeString` whilst in Delphi 2009 below as `AnsiString`, the same stands also for `Char` which is `WideChar` in Delphi 2009 up and `AnsiChar` below.

If so, then I think you have a problem at least with your buffer data length, because `Char = WideChar` takes 2 bytes and you were using [`StrLen`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.StrLen) function which returns the number of chars what cannot correspond to the data size of `number of chars * 2 bytes`.

I hope this will fix your problem, but I can't verify it, because I don't have your printer :)

```
type
  TPrinterData = record
    DataLength: Word;
    Data: array [0..255] of AnsiChar; // let's use 1 byte long AnsiChar
end;

function Convert(const S: AnsiString): string;
var
  I: Integer; // 32-bit integer is more efficient than 8-bit byte type
  T: string;  // here we keep the native string data type
begin
  T := '';
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
    T := T + IntToHex(Ord(S[I]), 2) + ' ';
  Result := T;
end;

procedure TFTestStampa.SpeedButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestInt: Integer;
  Command: AnsiString;
  BufferIn: TPrinterData;
  BufferOut: TPrinterData;
begin
  Printer.BeginDoc;

  try
    TestInt := PASSTHROUGH;

    if Escape(Printer.Handle, QUERYESCSUPPORT, SizeOf(TestInt), @TestInt, nil) > 0 then
    begin
      Command := Chr(10) + Chr(04) + '4';
      StrPCopy(BufferIn.Data, Command);
      BufferIn.DataLength := StrLen(Command);
      FillChar(BufferOut.Data, Length(BufferOut.Data), #0);
      BufferOut.DataLength := 0;
      Escape(Printer.Canvas.Handle, PASSTHROUGH, 0, @BufferIn, @BufferOut);

      ShowMessage(Convert(StrPas(BufferOut.Data)));
    end

  finally
    Printer.EndDoc;
  end;
end;
```